# Setting NODE_PATH in command line via script

Tags: node.js, bash

/home/karl/myapp/path.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentDir=$(
  cd $(dirname "$0")
  pwd
) 

echo $currentDir
```

The script above echos the absolute path. I'd like to set the NODE_PATH variable as seen below with the echo'd value.

```
NODE_PATH=path.sh ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec
```

At the moment NODE_PATH is actually set to the string "path.sh" and not the absolute path that it echos.

So I'd like the result to be the same as `NODE_PATH=/home/karl/myapp/ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec` as an example.

Any ideas?

I've also tried the following: `bash path.sh | NODE_PATH="$currentDir" ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec`

Comment: @Inian I'm sorry o/p?

Comment: @Inian Ah! I've added the "desired" output. It's the command at the bottom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Arif Khans answer I was able to come up with the three following:

```
NODE_PATH="$(dirname $(readlink -f ./path.sh))" ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec

NODE_PATH="$(bash path.sh)" ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec

NODE_PATH="$(pwd)" ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, it will be consider as string. You need to inside `$(COMMAND)` like in your case `"$(sh path.sh)"` . So complete command will be

```
NODE_PATH="$(sh path.sh)" ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks! You helped me crack it. My answer is posted, upvoted for the help!

Comment: @KarlMorrison if this answer help you then you may like to accept it as well

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by executing the below command:

```
NODE_PATH=`./p.sh`'./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill --reporter spec'
```

whatever is in between `` is basically executing that particular command and then append what is needed.